# How to RegExp file with Spark?

Tags: regex, scala, mapping, apache-spark, rdd

I have `UDP_file.txt` containing:

```
2014-03-02 07:59:37;source-address=123.235.78.125 source-port=1780
2014-03-02 07:59:37;source-address=123.235.132.181 source-port=56399
2014-03-02 07:59:37;source-address=123.234.141.253 source-port=49170
2014-03-02 07:59:37;source-address=123.234.104.225 source-port=39123
2014-03-02 07:59:37;source-address=123.234.104.225 fake-port=0000
```

What I need to do is :

- load file,
- RegExp it,
- lines than match pattern save in file 'good_records.txt',
- lines than don't match pattern save in file 'bad_records.txt'

.

```
val file_in = sc.textFile("UPD_file.txt")
val FullName = """(^.{19}).+source-address=([^"]+) source-port=([^"]+)""".r
```

When I test pattern on one row it works:

```
scala> val FullName(ip,sa,sp) = "2014-03-02 07:59:37;source-address=10.114.104.225 source-port=3912
ip: String = 2014-03-02 07:59:37
sa: String = 10.114.104.225
sp: String = 39123
```

or

```
scala> "2014-03-02 07:59:37;source-address=10.115.78.125 source-port=1780" match { case FullName(ip,sa,sp) }
(2014-03-02 07:59:37,10.115.78.125,1780)
```

But I have no idea how to use it on each line of a loaded file.

```
file_in.AndWhatNow?
```

Can you help? I will be grateful for any suggestions.
Pawel

Comment: If only there were the `.AndWhatNow?` method. it would go well will `andThen`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split input into separate lines and map over it

```
val FullName = """(.+);source-address=(.+) (?:fake|source)-port=(.+)""".r

val names = file_in map { line =>
    val FullName(ip, sa, sp) = line
    (ip, sa, sp)
}
```

**Update**

To split results by port type capture it in a group and then apply `partition` method

```
val FullName = """(.+);source-address=(.+) (fake|source)-port=(.+)""".r

val (goodOnes, fakes) = file_in map { line =>
  val FullName(ip, sa, pt, sp) = line
  (ip, sa, pt, sp)
} partition { _._3 == "source" }
```

Comment: You didn't say you're dealing with RDDs. I've updated answer.

Comment: Hmm. I get this error:
<console>:16: error: recursive value x$1 needs type
       val names = file_in map { line => val FullName(ip, sa, sp) = line(ip, sa, sp) } pointing on ip in FullName(ip,...

Comment: What's interesting I get this error when I put val names = etc in one line. When I copy your code it works fine. Is there any requirement to put this code into separate lines?

Comment: And how can we split result into separate rdds? lines that contain source-port go to 'good_records', lines that contain face-port go to 'bad_records'?

Comment: When writing it in one line you should separate expressions with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

With previouse solutions we get an error when line doesn't match the pattern. 
And if we want return different values for line that match the pattern and something else for those that don't or event match different patterns use this code:

```
val names = file_in map { line => line match { 
  case FullName(ip,sa,sp) => (ip,sa,sp) 
  case Second_FullName(val1, val2) => (val1, val2) 
  case _ =>  Nil
}
}
```